# find <p> element by the inner text using cypress

Tags: cypress, element

trying to get the p element by the inner text -> age
not using contains

```
<p data-cy="displayName_text>
"age"
<div class = "styles_param_eVD6N>
</div>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the `childNodes` property of the element to access the inner text.

`childNodes` returns both the text and the `<div>`, the text is first so use index 0.

```js
cy.get('p[data-cy="displayName_text"]')
  .then($p => $p[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue.trim())
  .should('eq', 'age')
```

Or use jQuery `.text()` method as the conversion:

```js
cy.get('p[data-cy="displayName_text"]')
  .then($p => $p.text().trim())
  .should('eq', 'age')
```

Or use Cypress `.invoke()` to do the same

```js
cy.get('p[data-cy="displayName_text"]')
  .invoke('text')
  .invoke('trim')
  .should('eq', 'age')
```

Or you could match it with a regex (`\s*` means spaces and newlines)

```js
cy.get('p[data-cy="displayName_text"]')
  .invoke('text')
  .should('match', /\s*age\s*/)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using JavaScript and the querySelectorAll() method to filter the elements based on their inner text. Here's an example:

```
const targetText = "age";
const pElements = document.querySelectorAll('p');

for (const pElement of pElements) {
    if (pElement.textContent.trim() === targetText) {
        console.log('Found the target element:', pElement);
        break;
    }
}
```

This code snippet iterates through all `<p>` elements on the page and checks if their text content matches the target text "age". If it finds a match, it logs the target element in the console.

**Note that this approach is not as efficient as using a more specific selector**, but it should work if you cannot use `contains()` or other `CSS` selector functions.